# Http Client host name is null?

Tags: java, http-post, httpclient, httpresponse, hostname

When `HttpPost` method is with request body to URI "https://app_server.test.com:9100/processes" using `HttpClient` to execute the `HttpPost`, I get an Exception: **Host name may not be null**

Sample Code:

```
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://app_server.test.com:9100/processes.ashx"); 
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(jsonstring); 
input.setContentType("application/json"); 
postRequest.setEntity(input); 
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
    at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:79) ~[httpcore-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:501) ~[httpclient-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906) ~[httpclient-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805) ~[httpclient-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784) ~[httpclient-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter.doFilter(RequestDumperFilter.java:203) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: Can you add full stack trace?

Comment: updated the stack in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add how you create httpClient and what httpClient do you use. I try following code (with org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient, version 4.5.6)

```
    try
    {
        HttpClient   httpClient  = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost     postRequest = new HttpPost("https://google.com");
        StringEntity input       = new StringEntity("ttt");
        input.setContentType("application/json");
        postRequest.setEntity(input);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
```

It is returns correct response "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed".

It is a quite strange that you have a many of spring-framework classes in stack trace. Do you use a some spring-frameworks http client?

I recommend you:

1. Update your version of httpclient (use the latest),
2. Try to use other url, for example google.com or so on (of course, you received http error, like 405, but you can see that code is correct),
3. Try to use other httpClient classes or other way to do it (because httpClient 
   is deprecated now),

Comment: Could able to get a response, when a uri does not have any special characters. '_'  makes a difference in this uri.

Comment: Thanks @Viacheslav. Your reply was helpful.